# ios creating multiple-page pdfs

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf-generation

How would I go about creating a multiple page pdf from a scrolling view? I am trying to convert an invoice pdf and it is much longer than 1 page; not sure how to create more.

also while on this, the pdf also seems to be quite choppy in quality ( very rasterized ) - any tips to improve this? i realize it's not vectorized, hence the choppy look, just looking for a way to make it better? thanks

Comment: It can be help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483933/create-pdf-with-multiple-pages

Answer (score 0):

To create multiple pdf, after creating each page you can convert the entire page to an image an store it in an array, one by one. Then you can show each image from the array as scrollview if thats what you meant.

You can create pdf pages and write it to a file with following function. Call it for each page.

```
-(void)savePDFImageToDocumentDirectory:(UIImage *)pdfImage withPageNumber:(int )pageNumber{

NSString *tmpPngPath = PDFTempDirectoryPath;
NSString *pageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PDFPage%d.png",pageNumber];
NSString *imagePath = [tmpPngPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:pageName];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(pdfImage) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

}

You can follow two approaches tom create pdf. One through html method and the other is from xib files. Html method is fast but pdf will be of less quality. xib method gives you high quality pdf but uses a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy for the PDF generation to be remote you could use a service like Docmosis cloud services or Aspose to create the Document and stream it back to the device (or email it or both etc).

Typically these PDF tools wouldn't build documents from images like screen shots - you would send the data you want populated instead.  This means the quality is very good (and text is selectable etc) and multiple pages is expected making the PDFs more generally useful.

Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

Hope that helps.